# Retrieving child records in Entity Framework code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Generic Repository which has all the common operations. I have two tables Customer and Address. Address is referenced in Customer

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll() 
  {
      return context.Set<TEntity>();
  }
```

Below is my repository

```
Repository<Customer> customerRepostitory = new Repository<Customer>();

var cusotomerList = customerRepostitory.GetAll();
```

The above line just returning the customer list, its not including Address Details.
Can you suggest the best way to retrieve the child records when i call parent records.

Comment: can we see the Customer type declaration ? (probalby a virtual missing below the adresses)

Comment: Perfect.. Virtual is missing. Thank you. I don't know how to mark your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was the virtual, you just discover lazy loading, one of the way to handle child records. You should read about the other ways/strategiess : [eager loading and explicit loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) to discover which one is/are the best for your cases.